# Can I gather community opinions of a specific information security practice?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Say I want to know "do people on security.SE report bad practices in their corporate information security to corporate IT". Does the question belong to the main site, meta or shouldn't be asked?

Comment: @TildalWave I think questions that have multiple valid answers are ok here (the same way they are ok on pretty much any SE website). We have many such questions, and many are well received. On the other hand, questions that are only opinion based, or really more of a general survey are of course of-topic. I generally wouldn't see a problem with a questions like `Is it proper practice to report security issues in a company to the IT department?`. For me, that would fall under the topics incident response or policies.  Of course, the way OP phrased the question it's just a poll and of-topic.

Comment: Of course, to not get closed as too broad, my example question would need to have more details added in the question body. Still, I wouldn't say it's categorically of-topic. The chat is of course a great suggestion if the OP indeed only wants to start a poll, and doesn't want to know current best practices.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to run a yes/no poll.  Polling questions are off-topic on main sites but are usually acceptable on meta sites if suitably constructed.

This has been discussed on the main SE Meta [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233908/are-poll-style-questions-ever-acceptable-on-meta-sites).  Essentially, be clear what you are polling for and set a close date.